# Is there a non-archimedian valuation on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory

I was wondering whether there can be a (non-trivial) non-archimedian valuation on $\mathbb{C}$ (with value group contained in $\mathbb{R}$). My idea of constructing such a valuation would be to take some transcendent element $t\in\mathbb{C}$. Then the discrete valuation ring $\mathbb{Q}[t]_{(t)}$ gives a valuation on $\mathbb{Q}(t)$. But I was not able to decide whether one can extend it to all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually extend the $p$-adic valuation of $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb C$. Or you can use an isomorphism $\Bbb C\cong \overline{\Bbb Q_p}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The way you wrote the answer suggests that your statements are well-known. Could you point me to a reference?

Comment: @Hans it is proven in Engler/Pretzel _Valued Fields_ that one can always extend valuations. The second statement follows from the fact that two algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic and cardinality are isomorphic.

Comment: One should replace cardinality by "transcendence degree over the prime field" in my previous comment. But in the uncountable case, this agrees with the cardinality.